# How to make APIM Policy changes upon certain flag and Mock success repose upon certain conditions Operation wise

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

Need to make changes in APIM policy changes upon certain flags And need to set up mock success repose upon certain conditions.

I use the below condition for these but at the time of saving these I get errors like:

> 'true' is an unexpected token. Expecting white space. Line 51, position 56.

```xml
.
.
.
.
Here After the first condition, I add one more condition 
<otherwise>
    <when condition="{{Flagname-Flag}} == "true")"> --'true' is an unexpected token. Expecting white space. Line 51, position 56.
    <!-- Policies to apply when the flag is true -->
        <return-response>
            <set-status code="200" reason="Ok" />
            <set-body>
                {    
                    "message": "Service is currently under maintenance. We will get back to you shortly."           
                }
            </set-body>
        </return-response>
    </when>
    <otherwise>
        <set-backend-service base-url="{{data present here}}" />
    </otherwise>
</otherwise>
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: can you please share the detailed information and your requirement as in what is your expectation?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use a named value in the [choose-policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/choose-policy).
The value has to be stored in a variable `featureFlag`:

```xml
<set-variable value="{{Flagname-Flag}}" name="featureFlag" />
```

The existing `otherwise` path needs a child of type `choose` to proceed with the when condition.

Finally, the when condition compares the value of the variable:

```xml
<when condition="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("featureFlag") != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("featureFlag")) && context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("featureFlag") == "true")">
```

The complete API policy:

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <set-variable value="{{Flagname-Flag}}" name="featureFlag" />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@("lorem" == "ipsum")" />
            <otherwise>
                <choose>
                    <when condition="@(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("featureFlag") != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("featureFlag")) && context.Variables.GetValueOrDefault<string>("featureFlag") == "true")">
                        <return-response>
                            <set-status code="200" reason="Ok" />
                            <set-body>{    
                                    "message": "Service is currently under maintenance. We will get back to you shortly."           
                                }</set-body>
                        </return-response>
                    </when>
                    <otherwise>
                        <set-backend-service base-url="{{data-present-here}}" />
                    </otherwise>
                </choose>
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

[image]

[image]